# searching for numbers in a list

Tags: python

If I have output that looks like this

```
[[121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111],
 [82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 110],
 [83, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 72, 109],
 [84, 51, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 42, 71, 108],
 [85, 52, 27, 10, 9, 8, 7, 20, 41, 70, 107],
 [86, 53, 28, 11, 2, 1, 6, 19, 40, 69, 106],
 [87, 54, 29, 12, 3, 4, 5, 18, 39, 68, 105],
 [88, 55, 30, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 38, 67, 104],
 [89, 56, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 66, 103],
 [90, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 102],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101]]
```

how do I get it to where I can find and print a certain number and the numbers surrounding it? This is my code.

```
dim = 11
dx, dy = [0, 1, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1, 0]
x, y, c = 0, -1, dim**2
m = [[0 for i in range(dim)] for j in range(dim)]
for i in range(dim + dim - 1):
        for j in range((dim + dim - i) // 2):
                x += dx[i % 4]
                y += dy[i % 4]
                m[x][y] = c
                c -= 1
print(m)
b = c.index(num)
print(b)
a =('\n'.join([' '.join([str(v) for v in r])for r in m]))
print(a)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: My program needs to be able to print put a certain number and the one to the left, right, above, and below it. For some reason the output was copied weird. It should be in a square shape.

Comment: I have no clue what your code has to do with your question; and probably the reason is I don't know what all this `x`, `y`, `c`, `dx`, `dy` is supposed to be.  What is `dim`?

Comment: dim is the dimension of the spiral. In this instance it was 11. Dim was labeled earlier in my code that I didn't post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that list-of-lists is called `lol`:-):

```
def neighbors(lol, anum):
    for i, row in enumerate(lol[1:-1]):
        try: where = row.index(anum)
        except ValueError: continue
        if where==0 or where==len(row)-1: continue
        for j in range(i, i+3):
            print(lol[j][where-1], lol[j][where], lol[j][where+1])
        print()
```

This embodies several assumptions, such as: (A) you don't care for hits on the first or last row or column since they don't have all the neighbors you want to print, and also (B) you don't care about multiple "hits" in a single row but (C) do care about "hits" in multiple rows.

Of course all such assumptions can be changed but that requires you to be **much** more precise in your specs than you've been so far:-).

The `print` format assumes either Python 3 or a `from __future__ import print_function` if you're stuck with Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

First in this case as `c` is a int value hasn't attribute `index` . so the following command will raise an `AttributeError` .

```
b = c.index(num)
```

and for get the desire result all that you need here is reversing the `r` list in following command , and for print you can use `format` :

```
a =('\n'.join([' '.join(["{:3}".format(v) for v in r[::-1]])for r in m]))
```

so the result will be :

```
111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
110  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
109  72  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  83
108  71  42  21  22  23  24  25  26  51  84
107  70  41  20   7   8   9  10  27  52  85
106  69  40  19   6   1   2  11  28  53  86
105  68  39  18   5   4   3  12  29  54  87
104  67  38  17  16  15  14  13  30  55  88
103  66  37  36  35  34  33  32  31  56  89
102  65  64  63  62  61  60  59  58  57  90
101 100  99  98  97  96  95  94  93  92  91
```

Comment: thanks but my real issue is being able to find a certain number in the square and be able to print the 8 numbers surrounding it